# How to blur the background in photo booth?

Tags: photo-booth

When using photo booth, I see there is an 'Effects' button with many effects like 'Space Alien' and 'Dizzy'.

But if I want to simply blur the background a little, how do I do that?

Comment: I think that with PhotoBooth it is a simple app and unless there are plugins of some sort you are stuck with what it offers. You may have to look for another app that does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Photo Booth in macOS Catalina [no longer has the option for custom backgrounds](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251239423). If you have an older version of macOS, you can add your own background, which you can blur.

1. Take a picture using Photo Booth without you in it, such that it captures the background.
2. Blur the image using a photo editing application, such as Photoshop or one from [Tool to quickly hide/blur/redact text in screenshot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72971/37797).
3. In Photo Booth effects, on the last page for custom backgrounds, drag your image in.