# Light weight, free way to record a video with a blurred background using Mac webcam?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture, webcam, screen-recording, photo-booth

When recording a video, sometimes it's preferable to blur the background, especially when working from home or outside the typical office environment.

I didn't figure out [how to blur the background of a photo booth video recording](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/412180/290197), so I record without blurring the background. But blurring the background usually makes videos look much more professional. Example:

[image]

What is the quickest and easiest way to record a video from a mac webcam that blurs the background? (preferably using software that comes with macOS, but if not, something free and very light weight is preferred)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach to attain your goal is to use a video calling application in combination with screen recording.

For the video calling application I suggest [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) as it works in your browser, but you can also look into any other popular application like Teams, Zoom or Skype.

1. Go to [meet.jitsi.com](https://meet.jit.si) to start a video call in your browser. For other applications follow the steps they need to start a video call.
2. Configure the calling application to use your camera and microphone.
3. Configure background blurring.

   - In Jitsi you can go to the three dot menu in the lower right and select "Blur my background [BETA]".
   - Here are instructions for other applications: [Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780), [Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/210707503-Virtual-Background), [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/blogs/2019-02-background-blur/)
4. Now you should have a screen, showing live what is being recorded by your camera.
5. Open Quicktime, and follow [these steps](https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/record-your-screen-qtp97b08e666/mac) to record your screen, in particular the window of your video calling application.

This will generate a recording of your screen, and as that screen shows your webcam with a blurred background you will have a video of yourself with a blurred background.

Note that some video calling applications have a built in recording option, allowing you to skip step 5.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for Mac and Windows called ChromaCam.
It has minimum requirements such as MacOs 10.14 but it can accomplish this as well.